# Existence of wild regular abstract polytopes

Tags: co.combinatorics, abstract-polytopes

Is it possible for an edge to connect two non-adjacent vertices of a polygonal face in a regular abstract polytope? Here “adjacent” means that the two vertices are connected by an edge that is a facet of the face.

Comment: It is common to say that, if two vertices are connected by an edge, they are adjacent. So it seems your question might depend on the meaning of "edge" and "adjacent"?

Comment: I clarified the question.

Comment: I think this would violate "intersection property", as defined in the book by McMullen and Schulte.

Comment: @Dima, can you elaborate?

Comment: IIRC, it's the same intersection property as pops up in diagram geometries (in sense of Buekenhout-Tits). Flat geometries don't satisfy intersection property.

Comment: @Dima, I can see that the hemicube, as a flat geometry, does not have the intersection property. But I fail to see how this is relevant to whether the hemicube fulfills the requirements in this question. It is a fairly simple example and so are the requirements, so is it possible to point out which exact requirement it fails?

Comment: oops, sorry for noise. It's a good example, intersection property in sense of McMullen-Schulte holds just fine.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up! You had me confused for a while, and I further confused myself by trying to check it in Sage but goofing up the code. Indeed the hemicube has the intersection property (as in the McMullen-Schulte book, proposition 2B10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

An example is the hemicube ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicube_(geometry)), [Atlas of small regular polytopes](https://www.abstract-polytopes.com/atlas/24/12/3.html), [Weddslist](http://www.weddslist.com/rmdb/map.php?a=N1.1p)). It has four vertices, six edges (every pair of vertices is connected by an edge), and three square faces. The funny thing is that every face also contains all four vertices, but in different orders.

Here is a nice hemicube picture from Wikipedia (by user Apocheir, [source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hemicube.svg)). We can see, for example, that vertices $a$ and $b$ are connected by an edge ($1$), which lies on two faces (I and II), but not on the third face (III).

So edge $1$ connects vertices that, on another face (III), are nonadjacent.

[image: Hemicube]